# Can't exchange data between Android phone and Arduino with NFC module, using HCE

Tags: android, arduino, nfc, apdu, hce

Please, I need any help to solve my problem.
I can't exchange data normally between Android (4.4.2) phone and Arduino with NFC module, using HCE. 
I took example from Android samples, and slightly changed to return just IMEI number.

```
public byte[] processCommandApdu(byte[] commandApdu, Bundle extras) {
    if (Arrays.equals(SELECT_APDU, commandApdu)) {
        String data = ((TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getDeviceId();
        return ConcatArrays(data.getBytes(), SELECT_OK_SW);
    } else {
        return UNKNOWN_CMD_SW;
    }
}
```

On Arduino side, my code is:

```
void loop(){
    Serial.println("Waiting for an ISO14443A card");
    uint8_t success;

    success = nfc.inListPassiveTarget();
    if(success){
        Serial.println("Found something!");      
        uint8_t responseLength = 32;
        uint8_t response[32];
        uint8_t selectApdu[] = { 
             0x00, /* CLA */
             0xA4, /* INS */
             0x04, /* P1  */
             0x00, /* P2  */
             0x05, /* Length of AID  */
             0xF2, 0x22, 0x022, 0x22, 0x22, /* AID */
             0x00  /* Le  */};

        success = nfc.inDataExchange(selectApdu, sizeof(selectApdu), response, &responseLength);
        Serial.print("EX_RES:");
        Serial.println(success);

        if(success) {
            Serial.print("responseLength: "); 
            Serial.println(responseLength);
            for(int i=0; i<responseLength; i++){
                Serial.print(response[i]);
                Serial.print(", ");
            }
            Serial.println();
            Serial.println("========================");
        }
        else {
            Serial.println("Failed sending SELECT AID"); 
        }
    }
    else {
        Serial.println("Didn't find anything!");
    }

    delay(1000);
}
```

Initially, I was receiving "Failed sending SELECT AID", so I tried to figure out why. So i updated code of **inDataExchange** in **PN532.cpp** file. So now it looks like this:

```
// initially function was returning bool
uint8_t PN532::inDataExchange(uint8_t *send, uint8_t sendLength, uint8_t *response, uint8_t *responseLength){

uint8_t i;
pn532_packetbuffer[0] = 0x40; // PN532_COMMAND_INDATAEXCHANGE;
pn532_packetbuffer[1] = inListedTag;

if (HAL(writeCommand)(pn532_packetbuffer, 2, send, sendLength)) {
    return 2; // initially was false
}

int16_t status = HAL(readResponse)(response, *responseLength, 1000);
if (status < 0) {
    return 3;  // initially was false
}

if ((response[0] & 0x3f) != 0) {
    DMSG("Status code indicates an error\n");
    return 4;  // initially was false
}

uint8_t length = status;
length -= 1;

if (length > *responseLength) {
    length = *responseLength; // silent truncation...
}

for (uint8_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    response[i] = response[i + 1];
}
*responseLength = length;

return 5;  // initially was true
}
```

And now, I'm receiving such log output:

```
Waiting for an ISO14443A card
Found something!
EX_RES:5
responseLength1: 18
35, 51, 53, 55, 50, 52, 54, 48, 53, 52, 49, 57, 50, 55, 49, 57, 144, 0, 
========================
Waiting for an ISO14443A card
Found something!
EX_RES:4
responseLength1: 32
11, 51, 53, 55, 50, 52, 54, 48, 53, 52, 49, 57, 50, 55, 49, 57, 144, 0, 0, 36, 0, 0, 3, 5, 17, 2, 117, 0, 194, 1, 6, 7, 
========================
Waiting for an ISO14443A card
Found something!
EX_RES:4
responseLength1: 32
1, 51, 53, 55, 50, 52, 54, 48, 53, 52, 49, 57, 50, 55, 49, 57, 144, 0, 0, 36, 0, 0, 3, 5, 17, 2, 117, 0, 194, 1, 6, 7, 
========================
Waiting for an ISO14443A card
Found something!
EX_RES:4
responseLength1: 32
11, 51, 53, 55, 50, 52, 54, 48, 53, 52, 49, 57, 50, 55, 49, 57, 144, 0, 0, 36, 0, 0, 3, 5, 17, 2, 117, 0, 254, 0, 0, 0, 
========================
```

I understand that this result is incorrect, and value is unchanged buffer (because of error), except first digit, which is changing from time to time.
Sometimes I receive such strange log:

```
EX_RES:4
responseLength: 18
11, 219, 13, 51, 8, 187, 181, 0, 2, 54, 1, 1, 2, 140, 0, 7, 72, 1, 
EX_RES:4
responseLength: 18
1, 72, 1, 2, 37, 0, 4, 228, 4, 160, 4, 168, 7, 236, 2, 138, 50, 0,
```

What's the problem? Maybe someone encountered this problem? Maybe there is some problem with library, or I'm doing something wrong?

I'm using:

- Elechouse NFC Module v2.0
- Arduino UNO SMD R3
- NFC library from https://github.com/elechouse/PN532

Comment: The code and the log output do not match (e.g. no EX_RES2 and no responseLength2 used in the code you posted). Please update the question to include matching code/log output.

Comment: I still don't believe that the log output you gave is from the code above. Particularly in step three the first byte of the `response` buffer just magically changes to `35` again. In reality, if `inDataExchange` returns with error code 3, that byte would either remain `11` (if the array was allocated on the same memory as in the previous round) or the whole response buffer would contain random garbage (if the array was allocated on a different memory area as before).

Comment: That's rather difficult to say without seeing what you are actually doing (real code/real output).

Comment: Now I really updated, and wrote new log output. Also, one guy from arduino forum told me to set responseLength manually, so I did it, and now I can't see error 3, don't know is it related or not :)

Comment: Is your project open source?

Comment: @MeanEYE Actually, this project was just for my diploma.

Comment: @Nur4I thanks. Was hoping to get a head start on similar project. Am making NFC door lock which is suppose to accept NFC cards and Android application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working. First of all want to say that the problem arose because of my incompetence in Android programming (I'm totally newbie).

1. `responseLength` must be set manually, and ideally, must be equal to response buffer size (thanks to Traveller99 from arduino forum)
2. HCE will not work if the screen is off (here is the fun part :) )

   > Current Android implementations turn the NFC controller and the application processor off completely when the screen of the device is turned off. HCE services will therefore not work when the screen is off. HCE services can function from the lock-screen however.

Thanks to [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2425802/michael-roland) for trying to help!

Comment: For future reference for anyone who might encounter this thread having the same problem. I was just with the same issue but responseLength wasn't enough I had to add it 1 I mean `responseLength + 1` as I'm communicating through SPI with my PN532 module, my guess is that as SPI COM uses full duplex it needs + 1 frame to get the last byte.

Comment: Can you give us Complete code of Android and Arduion?